# Como normalizar los campos tipo otros y especificar

Tags: base-de-datos

Disculpen tengo una duda, quiero normalizar los campos de especificar, ya que cuento con una base de datos de alumnos que cuenta con los siguientes campos:

```
id, 
nombre, 
apellido paterno, 
apellido materno, 
fecha de nacimiento, 
país de origen, 
estado, 
ciudad, 
dirección, 
valor_contabilidad, 
valor sistemas, 
valor_administración
```

y empece separando por el país de origen y el estado de esta manera

```
pais

id_país nombre país
------------------------------------
1        mexico
2        otro

estado

id_estado   nombre_estado   id_país
------------------------------------
1            df              1
2            otro            2
```

El problema es que en caso de que los campos sean de otro país u otro estado debo especificar tanto el país como el estado y no lo tengo muy claro, ademas me gustaría ver si puedo separar las otros campos de las materias a las cuales se les debe asignar un valor del 1 al 5 y no debe repetirse.

Answer (score 0):

La forma lógica de organizar sería metiendo en el orden jerárquico el campo `ciudad`. O sea: *una `ciudad` pertenece a un `estado` y éste pertenece a un `pais`*.

**pais**

```
id_país nombre país
------------------------------------
1        mexico
2        otro
```

**estado**

```
id_estado   nombre_estado   id_país
------------------------------------
1            df              1
2            otro            2
```

**ciudad**

```
id_ciudad   nombre_ciudad   id_estado
------------------------------------
1            ciudad de mx       1
2            jalisco            2
```

En cualquier tabla en la que pongas la ciudad `1` podrás saber, uniendo las tablas `ciudad, estado, pais` a qué estado y qué país pertenece esa ciudad.

Si montas el modelo de datos así, podrás descargar tu tabla `alumno`, quedando así:

**alumno**

```
id, 
nombre, 
apellido paterno, 
apellido materno, 
fecha de nacimiento, 
id_ciudad, 
dirección, 
valor_contabilidad, 
valor sistemas, 
valor_administración
```

Como puedes ver, ahora pusimos la columna `id_ciudad` y por ese valor, uniendo las tablas, llegaremos a obtener el nombre del estado o del país. Viendo que tienes una columna `direccion`, si en el modelo que presentas la columna `ciudad` se refiere a la dirección puede que haya que refinar todavía un poco más el modelo, manejando una tabla `direccion` que agrupe la ciudad, la calle, etc.

### Restricciones para evitar duplicados

Una cosa muy importante es que pongas las restricciones adecuadas en cada tabla.

Por ejemplo, la tabla `estado` debe tener una restricción `UNIQUE (nombre_estado,id_pais)` que impedirá que un mismo país tenga dos estados con el mismo nombre. La restricción no puede ser sólo en base a `nombre_estado` porque es un dato que se puede repetir en paises diversos.

Del mismo modo, la tabla `ciudad` debe tener una restricción `UNIQUE(nombre_ciudad,id_estado)`, porque el nombre de la ciudad jamás se repetirá en un mismo estado.

Lo otro que preguntas no se entiende muy bien. Si lo aclaras puedo completar la pregunta con esa duda adicional.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema es que es para una pagina web y tengo que agregar que si es de otro país o un estado diferente, debe especificar de que país o de que estado es, y eso es lo que no se como agregar a las tablas, había pensado en una tabla intermedia que es donde se agregarían los nuevos países o estados, y con lo que respecta a la otra duda me refería a como podría normalizar una tabla donde vengan los tipos de carreras y que se les pueda asignar un valor del 1 al 5 y que esta valoración quede asignada al alumno

Comment: @user152069 no entiendo mucho tu comentario. Leo que dices *tengo que agregar que si es de otro país o un estado diferente*. Eso debe reflejarse en la lógica del programa, no en la base de datos. O sea, cuando obtienes los datos comparas si es del país `X` y en base a eso haces lo que hayas que hacer. Una cosa es la estructura de datos y otra algunas comparaciones que haya que hacer a nivel de programación. Creo que intentas meter la lógica en la BD y eso suele ser un error de enfoque.

Comment: ok, muchas gracias, creo que si me confundí, y una disculpa por hacer la pregunta un poco confusa